# Dividing an array into partitions NOT evenly sized, given the points where each partition should start or end, in python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

How do I divide a list into smaller not evenly sized intervals, give the ideal initial and final values of each interval?

I have a list of 16383 items. I **also** have a separate list of the values at which each interval should end and the following should enter.

I would need to use the given intervals to assign each element to the partition it belongs to, depending on its value.

I have tried reading stuff, but I encountered only the case when given the original list, people split it into evenly sized partitions...

Thanks

Blaise

Comment: When you say "interval" - do you have run lengths of a partition, such that each is immediately after another, or a range that defines a partition...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you need something like that

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> i = [[1, 5], [5, 8], [8, 20]]
>>> [a[x:y] for x, y in i]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

or, as [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) suggested in comments:

```
>>> [a[slice(*s)] for s in i]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: You could extend this slightly by allowing the functionality of `slice`, eg: `[a[slice(*s)] for s in i]`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use slices:

```
>>> c = [0,3,5,10]
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    
>>> [l[c[i]:c[i+1]] for i in range(len(c)-1)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just one more variant:

```
a = range(20)
b = [3, 5, 8, 17]
map(lambda x, y: a[x : y], [0] + b, b)
```

gives:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

By list comprehension,

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> b = [3, 5, 8, 17]
>>> [a[x : y] for x, y in zip([0] + b[:-1], b)]
```

Explanation:

```
[0] + b[:-1]
```

gives

```
[0, 3, 5, 8]
```

Then

```
zip([0] + b[:-1], b)
```

gives the boundary

```
[(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 8), (8, 17)]
```

Finally iterates through list comprehension to get

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For each range in your limits list create an empty list plus one for the overflow values as a tupple with the max value in the list and the min value for that list, the last one will have a max on None
2. For each value in the values list run through your tupples until you find the one that your value is > min and < max or the max is None.
3. When you find the right list append the value to it and go on to the next.